# UK Visa - will we get it?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, visa-rejections

My husband and I are traveling to the UK for our honeymoon after getting married.

I have traveled quite a bit previously, but I have had one UK visa rejection four years ago, as I was careless and did not submit the proper documents. However I was able to get approved after that.

My husband however has traveled less; he has also had a rejected UK visa application seven years ago, although he never applied again.

We are applying next week with lots of documents, and we both have enough money in our accounts to show we will return back to our job and business.

What do you think our chances of getting the visa are? Are there any documents we should specifically include in our application?

Comment: Hi there, I've proposed an edit to your post which makes it a bit easier for others to read, but one thing we might need you to clarify for us: what country are you and your husband applying from? i.e. where are you citizens?

Comment: You should carefully read the guidance and ensure you're submitting all the documents they ask for, not randomly piling up documents they don't want. Beyond that, all you can do is submit the best application you can and hope for the best; asking us what the chances are is inherently subjective and not something we can really do.

Comment: This question might be on-topic if you reworded it to ask if UK immigration officers no longer take into account old visa rejections once they are older than some fixed number of years.